# Can we add trigger on a Queue

Tags: triggers, queue, salesforce, apex

I want to add a run a apex code when a user is entered/remove in any queue.

Basically I want to have a trigger point after insert and after update on a Queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no you cannot.

Queues are in the Group table with a Type of "Queue". What you really want to listen for is insertion and deletion of GroupMembers. That SObject is not available in triggers.

You can schedule a job to act on GroupMembers added to the table or the Recycle Bin since the last time the job ran.

Thanks,
Matt